# Show Data From Page-body to Modal-body

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show data from Body Their id(name + type) to Model Body. also i want data in page body as label but in model as input.
I want when edit click on Edit Button and open model have data in card to edit it.

https://codepen.io/fadynabilofficial/pen/PobJvER

```
<div class="container px-4 py-5 mx-auto">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="row px-1">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8"> 
                            <label class="form-control-label" id="name">Cheesecake With Flavor</label>
                             <label class="form-control-label" id="type">Chocola</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 mt-2">
                        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between px-4">
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn-block btn-edit" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" id="submit"> 
                            Edit 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal"
            tabindex="-1"
            aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true"> 
            
            <div class="modal-dialog"> 
                <div class="modal-content"> 
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <input id="name">
        
                        <br>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="submit"> 
                            Submit 
                        </button> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: did you tried something to achieve above ?

Comment: No, I didn't tried